# How to limit folder/sub folders/files access to a program only?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, encryption, limit

I am creating a c# winforms application.

And I have a folder ScanRepository, and I want to prevent other programs and windows users to open this folder, sub folders and files, with a kind of password or a key, and to be able to open them in my c# code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
        textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
   }
}

private void btnLock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {

      string folderPath = textBox1.Text;
      string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;// getting your adminUserName
      DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);
      FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName,  FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny)

      ds.AddAccessRule(fsa);
      Directory.SetAccessControl(folderPath, ds);
      MessageBox.Show("Locked");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }       
}

private void btnUnLock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     string folderPath = textBox1.Text;
     string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;// getting your adminUserName
     DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);
     FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName,  FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny)

     ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);
     Directory.SetAccessControl(folderPath, ds);
     MessageBox.Show("UnLocked");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: @medomedo Do you have the permission to copy the whole content of that blog post to Stack Overflow? The blog post is unlicensed and Stack Overflow is completely under a Creative Commons License.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just an example code not the whole content of the blog.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is that most things that let your user in, will let other apps in.. if you lock a folder to a user, while that folder is unlocked to that user other apps can see in too cos the user can see in.

best way is to have a service running as an account that the user cant use. Then, you lock the access to only that account (and system, if you want backups of it), then you make a service that handles any access to those files and lists etc it interfaces with your app.. so in your users eyes they have access, in essense they dont.